# How to fix the netty SSL SSLHandshakeException exception?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, netty, spring-webflux

In our Project, we use **Netty** as webserver, In spring boot project.
we would like to enable HTTPS and SSL in the project.
we added the certificate to the truststore by keytool.

```
keytool -keystore truststore.jks -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "try" -file "test.cer" -keypass pass -storepass pass
```

Than added the keypath and keystore information in project yaml file as :

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: 'truststore.jks'
    key-store-password: "pass"
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-alias: "try"
```

but eveytime we try to send request to https://127.0.0.1:8080

we get below exception :

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000ae:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_CERTIFICATE_SET
    
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000ae:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_CERTIFICATE_SET
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of **key store in java**,

- Truststore
- Keystore

**Truststore:** stores all public keys that need to be added to communicate with the third-party systems.
**Keystore:** contains the private key.

**I was putting the public key in Keystore and was the problem.**